# Getting rid of hard coded source and header file names in Makefile, just compile all source code in specified directories and output executable

Tags: c, makefile

This is my `Makefile`, What I like to do is remove source files names and header file name from my `Makefile`. Is this possible, I have seen `Makefiles` where hard coded source and header file name are not present but they compile the code and output executable. How to do this, The reason I am asking  is because I may make more source files and header files so I like to get rid of source and header file names from my Makefile which may be easy to handle for me. May be just compile source code in all specified directories and output executable

```
FUNCS = funcs/
HEADERS = headers/
HEADER_FROM_FUNCS_DIR=../$(HEADERS)

lh : $(FUNCS)test_func.o $(FUNCS)proto.o $(FUNCS)thread.o test.o
    cc -o lh $(FUNCS)test_func.o $(FUNCS)proto.o $(FUNCS)thread.o test.o 

proto : $(FUNCS)proto.c $(HEADERS_FROM_FUNCS_DIR)/test.h
    cc -c $(FUNCS)proto.c
    
thread : $(FUNCS)thread.c $(HEADERS_FROM_FUNCS_DIR)/test.h
    cc -c $(FUNCS)thread.c


test_func : $(FUNCS)test_func.c $(HEADERS_FROM_FUNCS_DIR)/test.h
    cc -c $(FUNCS)test_func.c

test.o : test.c $(HEADERS)/test.h
    cc -c test.c

clean :
    rm lh $(FUNCS)test_func.o $(FUNCS)proto.o $(FUNCS)thread.o test.o
```

Comment: Yes, some people do that.  No, it is not good style.  There are ways that you could simplify your makefile and make it easier to maintain without removing the filenames altogether, and that would be a better goal.  Any way around, however, the question is too broad for SO.  But if the makefile presently works as-is, then you could consider asking for improvement suggestions over at [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [See chapter 10 on implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: The recipe for `lh` should almost certainly be re-written as `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $? $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)`  Don't worry about the header dependencies and just drop all the `*.o: *.c` rules; let the implicit rules work for you.

Comment: One additional style point on this: most users do not include a trailing slash on directory names -- that is, in the above, `FUNCS := funcs`, `proto : $(FUNCS)/proto.c ...`, etc.   Also lookup [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit) and [autogenerated dependencies](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)